# set value to session and get value from session using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't able to get and set to session Below is my code:

```
login_btnClick() {

        var NTLoginID = ((document.getElementById("NTLoginID") as HTMLInputElement).value);
        this._homeService.get(Global.BASE_USER_ENDPOINT + '/EmployeeDetailsApi?user_id=' + NTLoginID)
            .do(data => sessionStorage.setItem('session',JSON.stringify(data)))
            .subscribe(homes => { this.homes = homes; this.indLoading = false; },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);
        var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        alert(JSON.stringify(session));
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
    }
```

I just getting only null, not the exact value. Im getting value from `.do(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data)))`. I'm new to angular2 Kindly do help.

Comment: its because you are trying to get the value before setting up the value `var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');` line will be executed immediately without waiting for the result of  `this._homeService.get`

Comment: @jitender I set session before getting only. `.do(data => sessionStorage.setItem('session',JSON.stringify(data)))` . correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: `sessionStorage.getItem` will be executed before the line you mentioned above javascript doesn't wait for your `get` method to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http requests in Angular 2 (or pretty much anywhere) are asynchronous. That means once your code reaches .do() it doesn't wait for the response and instead continues running your program. Changing the code like this should fix your problem:

```
    this._homeService.get(Global.BASE_USER_ENDPOINT + '/EmployeeDetailsApi?user_id=' + NTLoginID)
        .do(data => sessionStorage.setItem('session',JSON.stringify(data)))
        .subscribe(homes => { 
              this.homes = homes;
              this.indLoading = false; 
              var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
              alert(JSON.stringify(session));
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
        },
        error => this.msg = <any>error);
```

Comment: awesome bro @Alex. Working